# can't write an avro file

Tags: java, scala, avro

I need to write json to Avro. I am using [this](https://github.com/GenslerAppsPod/scalavro) library to make it easier to work with scala.

I have the following code snippet:

```
case class FriendRequestAcceptedGson(
  AppId: Int, CallingAppId: Int, Platform: Int, EventId: Int, Event: String, 
  EventTimestamp: Long, EventTxnId: String, UserId: String, SessionId: String, 
  TrackerVersion: String, CollectorVersion: String, EtlVersion: String,
  MktMedium: String, MktSource: Int, MktTerm: String, MktContent: String, 
  MktCampain: String,FromUserId: String, ToUserId: String)

val json =
      """{
            "AppId": 3,
            "CallingAppId": 3,
            "Platform": 1,
            "EventId": 1601,
            "Event": "FRIEND_REQUEST_ACCEPTED",
            "EventTimestamp": 12345,
            "EventTxnId": "0D4F2FA0-05CF-11E4-9191-0800200C9A66",                   
            "UserId":"m64761362002",
            "SessionId":"337be570-d9e6-11e3-9def-0015c5ff1d1f",
            "TrackerVersion": "proxy",
            "CollectorVersion": "flume",
            "EtlVersion": "json-hdfs",
            "MktMedium": "cpc",
            "MktSource": 1,
            "MktTerm": "abc",
            "MktContent": "abc",
            "MktCampaign": "def",                   
            "FromUserId":"m733999",
            "ToUserId":"m11114444"                  
       }"""

    val avroType = AvroType[FriendRequestAcceptedGson]

    avroType.io.readJson(json) match {
      case Success(readResult) => {
        println(readResult)
        val outStream: java.io.OutputStream = new FileOutputStream("FriendRequestAcceptedGson.avro")
        avroType.io.write(readResult, outStream)        
        outStream.close
      }
      case Failure(cause) => print("Failed: "); print(cause)
    }
```

But when I try and use Avrotools with the Avro file just generated, then I get this error:

```
[lee@lee etl]$ java -jar avro-tools-1.7.7.jar tojson FriendRequestAcceptedGson.avro
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Not an Avro data file
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader.openReader(DataFileReader.java:63)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.DataFileReadTool.run(DataFileReadTool.java:71)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.run(Main.java:84)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(Main.java:73)
```

What am I doing wrong? [This](https://github.com/GenslerAppsPod/scalavro/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/com/gensler/scalavro/io/AvroTypeIO.scala#L44) is the method from the libary that I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalavro is great! But right now it can't write proper datafiles (it writes avros, but none of the header info).

Until an awesome person contributes that feature, you can write avro datafiles in Scala (i.e. use a Scala case class to represent the record) by:

a) annotating your `case class FriendRequestAcceptedGson` with `@AvroRecord` and using standard Java Avro to write to a file as in [these tests](https://github.com/julianpeeters/avro-scala-macro-annotations/blob/master/tests/src/test/scala/AvroRecordTests/AvroRecordNestedPrimitivesTest.scala).

b) being brave and trying out this relatively untested fork of [Salat-Avro](https://github.com/julianpeeters/salat-avro).